# Is scheduling 50+ download tasks at once a wrong approach?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

Is scheduling 50+ download tasks a wrong approach? By “scheduling” I mean creating `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` from a `NSURLSession` with “background” configuration and calling `[task resume]`. So I’m launching all tasks right away, but files are downloaded 2-3 at a time which is just what I need. Although I do get occasional time outs, which makes me wonder if it is the right approach to schedule everything and let the session handle the rest. Or should I have my own scheduling logic? There’s been a lot said about background transfer server when it comes to large files but I did not find much on downloading multiple (up to 300-400) small (3-10 mb) files. What would you do?

Comment: No I don't own the server side, unfortunately there is no way to group them.

Comment: have you set / changed `HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost`? middleware is a way to group them...

Comment: Hm, what would you set it to? I don't mind the session to decide the number of simultaneous downloads.

Comment: default is 4 for iOS, you could try a little lower and test the timeouts

Comment: Also you can configure not only the loading timeout. I'm pretty sure theres a second timeout for server response. You might increase that as well...